# Simple question of matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Is the vector space $\mathbb R^{mn}$ the same as $\mathbb R^{nm}$?

I need to know this to answer a question for Calculus, couldn't find it anywhere else.

Comment: How have you defined those spaces?

Comment: What do you know about *isomorphic spaces*? What do you know about their bases?

Comment: The vectorization of a m*n matrix and a n*m matrix

Answer (score 1):

Since $mn=nm$, they are the same.

If you think about the vector space of *matrices* instead, rather denoted by $\Bbb R^{n\times m}$, well, actually it is *not the same* as $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$, but they are *isomorphic*, also isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{mn}$, because each of them has dimension $nm$.

$\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ could be defined as the set of all functions $n\times m\to\Bbb R$, where $n$ as set denotes $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ and similarly for $m$. These are totally different entities as the functions $m\times n\to\Bbb R$ (unless $n=m$), but there is a natural correspondence between them, of course.

Answer (score 0):

By the commutativity of multiplication, $mn = nm = k$. So

$$\mathbb{R}^{mn} = \mathbb{R}^{k} = \mathbb{R}^{nm}$$

Comment: I agree. But I believe that the OP is talking about $(\mathbb{R}^{m})^n$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{n})^m$.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I'll edit my answer accordingly when the OP confirms this suspicion.